# Uploading an image to a server in Android using HTTP POST; Server does not seem to receive image

Tags: php, android, image, http, post

I am attempting to upload an image file from the Android's SD storage to a server. The code I have used will follow, however when checking the data the server has received, the server verifies communication is successful, but does not show that data has been posted.

```
private class postData extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {
     protected void doInBackground() {

    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
    DataInputStream inputStream = null;

    String pathToOurFile = "/sdcard/confirmed.jpg";
    String urlServer = "irrelevant";
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary =  "*****";

    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

    try
    {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile) );

        URL url = new URL(urlServer);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Allow Inputs & Outputs
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);

        // Enable POST method
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        System.out.println("posting");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

        outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile +"\"" + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // Read file
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        // Responses from the server (code and message)
        int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

        System.out.println(serverResponseCode+serverResponseMessage);

        fileInputStream.close();
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    //Exception handling
    }
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate() {
        //called when the background task makes any progress
     }

      protected void onPreExecute() {
         //called before doInBackground() is started
     }
     protected void onPostExecute() {
         //called after doInBackground() has finished 
     }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

I struggle to give specifics, but if any are required please ask and I shall try to give them.

Comment: I have near identical code to yours for posting files via Java. The only two differences I can see are that your line end uses `\r\n` whereas I use `\n` and that where you pass the filename 'pathToOurFile' you may be passing a path rather than just a name. If neither of those changes help, I would presume that the server is not working correctly.

Comment: how are you accessing the file on the server?

Comment: In a similar fashion to the following code: `<?php
$target_path  = "./";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
 echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).
 " has been uploaded";
} else{
 echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>`

When accessing a debugging url the content of $_FILES should be visible.
I will test the Line End, however I am positive it should be a path being passed.

Comment: https://apps.taskpixie.com/ar/?debug=1 Here is the debug url, you should see an empty array as the first entry, this is where my data should be present.